# How to query jsonb array of hash elements for missing key/value pair in Rails 5/Postgres

Tags: arrays, postgresql, hash, ruby-on-rails-5, jsonb

I have a `jsonb` array attribute (`array_attr`) on a class (`Klass`) in my Rails 5 app. The array is an array of hashes. Some of the hashes contain keys that others do not. For example one array of hashes maybe

`[{'key1': 'val1'}]`

and another

`[{'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}]`

I would like to execute a query that returned all instances of `Klass` that do not have any elements in `array_attr` with `key2` defined.

Something like: `klasses = Klass.where("array_attr @> ?",[{"key2": nil}].to_json)`

---

I've also  tried doing it in the Postgres command line with the following:

`SELECT array_attr FROM klasses WHERE array_attr @> '[{"key2": null}]'`

A raw Postgres query as an answer would be helpful too. I'm not as fluent in it but if I can get it to work in command line Postgres then I'll be able to make it work in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a raw SQL query using Postgres' `jsonb_array_elements` method and use the `find_by_sql` method on `Klass`.

`sql = "select * from klasses, LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(array_attr) object where object ? 'key2' = false"`

`Klass.find_by_sql(sql)`

I can't speak to the performance of this solution but it gets the correct results. For my purposes, this is a one off query for handling some data migration things. It is not something that will be run often.